# using rsplit to split URL values held within a dictionary

Tags: python

I am using the following code to use rsplit to create a new variable for all the characters encountered after the first instance of the '=' sign when reading the string in reverse:

```
for url in URLS:
            aa = url.rsplit("=", 1)
            a = str(aa)
            print("a = ", a)
```

Here URLS is defined from all the entries in a dictionary consisting of multiple URLs in the format 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=n'. In this example the variable 'a' should be resolving to 'n'.

However, when I check the log a is resolving as '['http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=GOOG&f=' 'n']'.

I thought using this method I would extract the value 'n' as a string contained within the variable 'a'. Am I missing a step out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

aa[-1] is resolved to 'n'.

split and rsplit return an array of strings.

The second parameter in rsplit (here 1) just limits the number of splits to perform, i.e. with your example, it only splits on the last one (the first one starting from the end).

```
for url in URLS:
         try:
            aa = url.rsplit("=", 1)[1]
            print (aa)
         except IndexError as e:
            print ("No = found")
```

Comment: @jeanM...so i need to amend the code to for url in URLS:
            aa[-1] = url.rsplit("=", 1)
            a = str(aa)
            print("a = ", a) then?

Comment: aa = url.rsplit("=",1)[-1] or aa = url.rsplit("=",1)[1], the former returning always something, the latter raising an exception is '=' doesn't exists.